# "Couldn't update Privileged Access request" error when I try to approve "Privileged access requests" from M365 Admin Portal

Tags: office365, azure-synapse, pam

I'm running a Azure synapse pipeline to get Data Sets by using "Information Oversharing Template". I followed this [article](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/dataconnect-solutions/blob/main/ARMTemplates/MGDC%20Extraction%20Pre%20Reqs/readme.md).

I'm working on Azure synapse analytics workspace and trying to run "Unlock advanced analytics and insights using Microsoft 365 SharePoint datasets" Pipeline which is already available.
After configuring the pipeline, when I try to run, The status shows "Pending consent".
After configuring the required setting as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/privileged-access-management-configuration?view=o365-worldwide) .

From Admin center, when I try to approve the consent, It fails with an error “Couldn’t update privileged access request”. I have "Microsoft 365 E3 subscription +Microsoft 365 E5 Insider Risk Management add-on” License.[image: Privileged Access Management]

Kindly help me to resolve this issue and let me know what I'm missing here.. Thank you.

I followed this article to Configure PAM. [PAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/privileged-access-management-configuration?view=o365-worldwide) and Added one of my colleague as approver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Approve PAM requests, We need to create mail enabled security group and add this group for PAM approvers. very important thing is add users as members of this group who will be approving the requests. Adding them as owners will lead to the above PAM error. Found this through Exchange management scripts as to what privilege's should user have in order to approve the PAM requests.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when trying to approve a task request for `'Exchange\New-MoveRequest` where my user didn't have permission to approve such request. Adding the correct role and I was able to approve it.

In your case, make sure that your user has `Customer Lockbox Access Approver` role, which based on [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/customer-lockbox-requests?view=o365-worldwide#approve-or-deny-a-customer-lockbox-request), is the required role to approve the request.

Edit:
Forgot to mention that you can't self-approve the request.
Make sure that the whoever requested the data access is not your user.

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm using 2 users: one to request and other to approve. After adding the approver to Customer Lockbox Access Approver Role also, user is not able to approve the PAM request.

Comment: Hmm, I still believe is a permission issue. Could you elevate the approver user to have Global Administrator and try again? I assume that since you are using an E5 subscription, there are no security issues there. Let's rule out the permission issue then we can take it from there.

How is your policy for `Data Access Request` look like?

Comment: I just realized that I confused the E5 subscription with Renewable E5 which is a development tenant, so disregard my comment that you can just elevate the approver to highest role.